# How to get CPU Tempreature on different systems

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gpu, cpu

Im build simple CPU/GPU Monitor on QT. The question arose before me: how to get CPU/GPU tempreature from different OS?

Comment: Reading the CPU temperature is highly platform specific. I suggest you first figure out which platforms (OSes if you will) you want to support, then check for which of those SO already provides an answer, if any. Ask separate questions for the rest.

Comment: That depends on the OS and even on the type of CPU / GPU. You are going to have to write some platform specific code for each OS/CPU/GPU combination you want to support.

Comment: i dont think Qt has a class for this...

Comment: OK, for example platform is Linux. How I can get tempreature in Linux.

Comment: The book "Mastering Qt 5 - Lazar, Guillaume" is covering it with a task manger for all platforms, there is a free source code on www.packtpub.com even if you don't bought the book.